# having different font weight/type in different pages

Tags: css, fonts

I am having trouble with  my child-site. I have adjusted most of things on website but then I realize that the font-family and weight is different between the pages. Currently, I am overwriting the CSS through a css plugin, well it went well till facing this issue.

This is the CSS code for fonts ;

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
*{font-family:"Open Sans" !important;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  font-size: 18px;

}

p{
color:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50) !important;
   font-weight: 100 !important;
}

strong{
color: #1a9396 !important;
font-weight: 300 !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5{
color: #1a9396 !important;
font-weight: 100 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is one of your Revslider is loading `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300%2C400` after your CSS files load. This is causing all your fonts with `font-weight: 100;` to render as `Open Sans Light`. The culprit is your slider just below the header. This happens on all pages using revslider.

If you want the fonts to use `Open Sans Light`, either try removing your `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);` or change it to `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400);`

If you want normal font weights, try setting your `font-weight` back to `400` the issue is solved.

I am not familiar with Revslider, but it looks like you can stop loading the `Open Sans` font from the Revslider settings. Here is a link for instructions on doing so: https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/google-fonts/

Comment: thank you so much, you found out where the problem occurs. What i did for rest of the banners which causes 400 font-weight is putting text in 100 and make them invisible. The problem solved. Thank you buddy.